# Everything missing in Elementary OS

Tags: system, filesystem

I was attempting to fix a full root drive today and when I restarted my computer, the background was black, all of my settings are missing, my taskbar is back to the original installation options (though my apps seem to still be there), and all my files are missing (home folders all empty). Does anyone know what I might have done and how I might fix it (or if it's possible)? My main concern is retrieving the files, as much as I'd love if I could avoid a clean reinstall. I have been using Elementary OS and Ubuntu for quite a while but am still quite basic when it comes to tinkering under the hood.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more precisse? What was you issue? How you solved, step-by-step? Have you seen your /home folder? How many users have your system? Have all your users lost their files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you (or the system) have been created a new user. The following command list all users:

```
sudo awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd
```